# Azure Functions - Scaling And Memory Limitations

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've got some code that I'm considering putting into an Azure function and I've got a question/concern around the memory limitations and how the functions scale.

At the high end, the app could use about 800 mb of memory for a single execution, so if the max memory I can use is 1536mb, I can only have 1 concurrent execution without it running out of memory.

My understanding is that there can be a maximum of 10 instances, with x concurrent executions, but if the max capacity only allows me 1 running execution without it timing out, does that mean that I'd need to manually set the maximum concurrent executions to 1, and it would auto scale to a max of 10 instances, meaning I can only ever have 10 overall executions at a time?

If so, that is kind of a bummer, as I'd expect most executions to require far less memory than this.

It's a file manipulation function, so I can have a reasonably accurate guess about how much memory would be used based on the input file size, so if I restructure the back end to populate a variety of queues based on input size, I can have 1 queue for the high end stuff (with only 1 execution allowed at a time per instance), then divide it up into queues of other sizes and manually adjust the maximum concurrent instances, with a specific function targeting it's associated queue.

e.g. 1 queue for any file less than 1mb, as many executions as possible = 1 unrestricted function.
1 queue for 1mb-10mb input files, limited to 20 concurrent executions.
etc

It feels like more work than it should be, but it's not too much of a pain.

Does this seem like a sensible approach, or is there an easier way?

How exactly do you restrict the number of concurrent executions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of background explanations:

- Blob processing is handled behind-the-scenes by a queue. When we find a new (or modified) blob, we put that blob information into a queue message and enqueue it. That means that the settings available in host.json for queues also apply to blob processing.
- Queue configuration for functions is at the host-level and used by all queues. For your scenario to work, you'd need to create a function app for each batch of file sizes and configure the `queues` -> `batchSize` in [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json) for that app. Because you may run into memory restrictions, this may be your best bet anyway as you wouldn't have multiple functions running in parallel on the same host.

I don't believe we publish the maximum available instance count anywhere, but I can tell you that 10 is not a limit anymore. That was an early limit that has since been lifted. Your best bet is to give it a try and see how you scale. If you add [Application Insights support](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights-(Preview)), you can pretty easily see the number of instances currently running in the Live Stream.